# Ошибка вставки изображения в галлерею Android

Tags: android, permissions

Возникла проблема при парсе bitmap в URI:

`public static Uri getImageUri(Context c, Bitmap inImage){
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String result = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(c.getContentResolver(), inImage, "", "");
        return Uri.parse(result);
    }`

Вылезает такая ошибка:  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=15574, uid=10085 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

То есть у моей программы нет разрешения писать в External Storage, но...
У меня оно есть!

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Помогите чукче-программисту.